# How to change permission of mapped and committed memory space?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, win32-process

I had tried to read and write data to memory space in any process.
I used `VirtualProtect()` and `VirtualProtectEx()` functions to change permission of memory area.

```
if(!VirtualProtect(dwAddr, dwSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect))
{
    printf("VirtualProtect failed error %d", GetLastError());
}

CopyMemory(dwAddr, pBuffer, dwSize);
```

But I had error 5 (access denied) code, instead of good result.

So I checked memory information by using `VirtualQuery()` function.

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

VirtualQuery(dwAddr, &info, sizeof(info));
```

Result was following by:

```
info.Type = MEM_MAPPED;
info.State = MEM_COMMITED;
info.AllocationProtect = PAGE_WRITECOPY;
info.Protect = PAGE_READ;
```

Therefore I could not change permission of mapped and committed memory.

If there are another ways, please let me know it.

Comment: Please show a complete program so that we can see the critical call to `OpenProcess`. However, there is no point in using `VirtualProtect` since that operates on the calling process, and there is also no point in using `VirtualProtectEx` since `WriteProcessMemory` and `ReadProcessMemory` handle protection already.

Comment: from where you take this address ? this is address inside section. you create this section yourself ? or how ? what is section protection on create ? and instead `GetLastError()` show result of `RtlGetLastNtStatus()`

Comment: by idea you must got `STATUS_SECTION_PROTECTION` status which is mapped to `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` because initial section allocation protect is `PAGE_WRITECOPY` - incompatible with requested `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`. in case this is not image section

Answer (score 0):

If it's an external process you must run your application as administrator and you must use VirtualQueryEx().

You problem appears to be that you are not running as administrator.  If you're running as admin and using VirtualQueryEx() and is still fails, then you need to check your handle returned by OpenProcess() and make sure it's good.

Check return values and use GetLastError() after calling the APIs to further diagnose the issue.